# What is the difference between “Check it”, “Check it up” and “Check it out”?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any differences between "Check it", "Check it up" and "Check it out"?

Comment: Hello, again :-). I've seen the same avatar and the same question on ELL, so I guess I'm dealing with the same person - my comments on ELL apply here as well... Also, it is better to check the help centres of both websites and decide for which is the question suited better, and post only on one. If it would be more on-topic on the other website, someone will migrate it for you :-).

Comment: yup, that was me! and is it possible to remove the post on the other site sir/madam! ? I am not really accustomed with stack rules actually -_-

Comment: Uh, oh - well, since you are now getting answers in both places I'm not sure what's the best thing to do (this is why in the future it will be better for you if you have your question in one place - you would have your answers in one place as well). Generally, the moderators and high rep users have the power to migrate and close questions - you can always get their attention by flagging your own question and asking them to do move/close/delete the question for you. But I think someone else would know better what to do in this particular situation (I'm giving you tips for the future).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted from ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Check it" is either slang, as in attention grabbing, or it's an imperative command such as "The tire seems to be low on air..." "Check it."

"Check it up" it not something I've ever heard or read, but it sounds similar to "check it out" in the attention directing sense.

"Check it out" could be used instead of "Look at that!" or it could be used in the context of an item that is checked in and checked out, such as a library book.

TL;DR - meaning changes based on context.

Comment: Almost understood! but lets have an example. Let's assume that the we want to order someone to go and check if the computer is turned on or off. What should we use? "Go and check computer if it is turned off" or "Go and check the computer up if it is turned on"? And according to your answer i think we can not use "check out"  because it is often used for making attention.

Comment: I can only answer as a native English speaker, the ELL stack exchange usually has much more technically in-depth answers for learners. Anyhow, about your example-- in such a case I would say "Go check if the computer is on", "Go see if the computer is on", or "Make sure the computer is on", or "Tell me if the computer is on" depending on what I actually want you want to do.